# htaccess redirect entire domain to another, but make a custom redirection for specific url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to make some redirection for a domain.

Basically what I need is explained below.

Redirect entire domain.net to domain.com, but leave a custom redirect, like this:

```
domain.net/specific_url.html to domain.com/my_new_url.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.net
RewriteRule ^specific_url/? http://example.com/new_url [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The first part works ... (redirect all domain), but the exception (specific_url) does't redirect correctly. I am trying some modifications...

Comment: OK. I had just to put the second condition and rule above the first one.